# For Each If Statement - Skip NULLs

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have created a macro/some VBA to UPDATE a SQL Server table which works fine.

In short the code pulls a defined amount of records from the the table to excel and then the end user updates some specific information and then clicks update. A connection is created to the table and an SQL update statement runs which updates the relevant records.

The problem is where the user has not had to update a NULL field (NULL is in the SQL Server table but shows as 'empty' in Excel), when the use clicks update the SQL statement is forcing the NULL to an 'empty' entry.

To get round this I would like my code in the For Each statement to check if the cell/record is NULL or Empty and to skip to the NEXT row so the SQL Execute command is not carried out.

Here is the VBA in question:

```
cnn.Open cnnstr
Dim row As Range

   For Each row In [tbl_data].Rows
            uSQL = "UPDATE BREACH_DATA SET [VAL_BREACH_REASON] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_REASON").Index).Value) _
                & "' ,[VAL_BREACH_DETAIL] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_DETAIL").Index).Value) _
                    & "' ,[VAL_VALID] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_VALID").Index).Value) _
                        & "' ,[VAL_NOTES] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_NOTES").Index).Value) _
                            & "' WHERE  [ATD_NUMBER] = '" & (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("ATD_NUMBER").Index).Value) & "'"

            'Debug.Print uSQL
            cnn.Execute uSQL
    Next

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Any suggestions

Kind Regards
Dino

Comment: Why not just wrap each column with a NULLIF? IIRC, Excel can't distinguish between NULL and an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, thats where I was getting confused. I'll give that a whirl thank you.

Comment: Can I ask why the -1 for this question?

Comment: Whoever downvoted your question isn't likely to come back or offer an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating SQL Server data directly with strings from a cell. This is a classic example of opening a door for injection attacks - users can do all kinds of bad, bad things to your database. But given that you fix that here is a way to check that each cell is not empty or null (I assume if one of the fields are not empty or null you want to update...):

if not

```
 (
    (isempty(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_REASON").Index).Value) 
and isnull(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("VAL_BREACH_REASON").Index).Value)
and do same for the other cell values....
)
```

then update....

Comment: Thanks @benjamin-moskovits. Dont worry the users would not have a clue how to do this and its only for 2 possibly 3 specific users. I'll also give your suggestion a go and see how I get on and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Famous last words. As a colleague what could happen is someone's kid comes to work and trys adding a string to a column and if it works they are off to the races and your job could be in jeopardy. There are safe, not so hard ways, to make it almost impossible for someone to do this so please look into it.

Comment: I agree with @benjaminmoskovits about 100000%. Saying your users don't know how is exactly why this is such a bad idea. You don't care to code it correctly because you think you aren't at risk. Adding parameters to this query would take far less time and effort than defending why you don't do it right in the first place.

Comment: OK just to clear it up. The user can only select a value from a validation list which is locked down. No one can enter any random value and there are some VBA processes in place to check that certain cells meet certain criteria. The workbook including the VBA project are locked.

Comment: None the less it might good practice to parameterize your queries. It is a habit you should use every single time with no exceptions. Of course I would move the sql to a stored procedure because I don't like having sql embedded in the application. It makes it entirely too difficult to make a new front end.